# how to use third-party api in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I have an API and I need to call this API on o to submit button click of a form. how to do this on a WordPress website. can anyone explain to me the complete process is this possible to do? step by step explanation needed.

Comment: Is it possible? Absolutely. A normal way to add functions like that is to create a wordpress plugin. Do some research and you will find a lot of info about how to write wordpress plugins.

Comment: have to write plugin for specific api?

Comment: please check https://www.toptal.com/wordpress/wordpress-api-integration